# Django-table2 sort a column activate django-filter form

Tags: django, django-filter, django-tables2

I try this to enable filter on tables:
https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/filtering.html but when I click on a column title to order the table, the filter form is shown.

Why `{% if filter %}` is `True` when only ordering is requested?

Comment: I would think it's because in the list view nothing is being "filtered".

Comment: Issue already opened here: https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/issues/1521 with a nice patch